# NHibernate. Is there something like "CreateMultiSQLQuery" for batch SQL Statements

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I am using CreateSQLQuery to retrieve some entities with complex criteria and everything works fine with entity retrieval. But I want at the same query to use a Batch of SQL statements having the same result as this HQL Query (Want to make some record Counts) :

```
IList results = s.CreateMultiQuery()
   .Add("from Item i where i.Id > :id")
   .Add("select count(*) from Item i where i.Id > :id")
   .SetInt32("id", 50)
   .List();
```

Isn't there a way to create something like CreateMultiSQLQuery ? I am using NH 2.1 and SQL 2005.

Comment: Have you tried using the CreateMultiQuery method? ISQLQuery inherits from IQuery so it will compile, but i haven't tried to see if it will actually work

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adopt [Named SQL queries](http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2009/02/11/executing-native-sql-using-nhibernate-named-queries/) for that purpose.